# Algorithm to calculate the period where cumulative days within a rolling period exceeds a threshold

Tags: algorithms, databases

I'm struggling to think of the algorithm to transform one data set to another.
The problem I'm looking at is creating a dataset of periods of time where cumulative days absent within a period (eg 30 days) is greater than a certain threshold (eg 14 days). I can easily determine what sub-periods are within master-period the The dataset I'm working from is

| Absence_ID | Absence_Start | Absence_End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 | 16/01/2021 |
| 2 | 23/01/2021 | 30/01/2021 |

So in this example the rolling 30 day period would result in the cumulative sum of days exceeding 14 on the 29th of January and ending on the 11th of February

[image]

| Exception_ID | Exception_Start | Exception_End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29/01/2021 | 11/02/2021 |

But because the sub-periods vary in duration, start and number (n > 0) I'm struggling to get an initial insight into calculating Exception_Start and Exception_End.

Brute force checking each day isn't ideal due to the scale of the data.

Comment: ("The green period" includes columns with a second row value of 14. What happened to January, 31st?)

Comment: it's gone... xD

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year, but just wondering what you came up with?  I'm thinking of using a Queue.  I would initialize the queue with the known days and amounts and sum the entries.  Then with each new day, I would add it to the queue and add the amount for that day to the sum, and then remove an entry from the queue and subtract it's amount from the sum.  That way you're only adding/subtracting a couple numbers rather than trying to sum the whole thing each time.

You wouldn't necessarily need to initialize the queue with all the days that have 0 amounts.  Just do a peek() on the queue and only remove it if it is outside of 30 days.